# De onde está sendo carregado o php.ini nessa instância de Docker?

Tags: php, docker

Estou rodando uma instância que provêm deste [Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/bfe27759103fa6050601060165409b5b3be06395/5.6/jessie/apache/Dockerfile).

Aqui tenho parte do meu phpinfo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como podemos observar `Configuration File (php.ini) Path` está apontando para `/usr/local/etc/php`. Este valor foi passado na linha 31 do Dockerfile `ENV PHP_INI_DIR /usr/local/etc/php`.

Porém dentro dos meus sub arquivos de /usr/local/etc/ eu não encontro nenhum `php.ini`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como podemos observar no phpinfo o `Loaded Configuration File` está vazio.

Eu não sei de onde está vindo as configurações desta página. De onde está sendo carregado o php.ini?

Também não vejo o service do php para tentar reiniciá-lo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

UPDATE:
Eu tenho o php.ini nessa pasta:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui o Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:5-apache

# Update apt-get
RUN apt-get update

## list of installed library packages only =>  https://askubuntu.com/questions/434154/how-to-get-the-list-of-installed-library-packages-only
#ldconfig -v                # -v it will show the libraries versions
#ldconfig -v | grep libname # Use grep to find a specific library by name.
#RUN /sbin/ldconfig -p

## ListInstalledPackages => https://wiki.debian.org/ListInstalledPackages
#RUN dpkg-query -l

## NOTE:
##need setup php variables date and maxupload file and others variables. ==> https://howto.biapy.com/en/debian-gnu-linux/servers/php/manage-php-ini-options-from-command-line-on-debian

##Install FFmpeg on Debian  => https://superuser.com/questions/286675/how-to-install-ffmpeg-on-debian
#https://www.johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/
## System modules


#RUN apt-get install deb-multimedia-keyring
#RUN apt-get update
#RUN apt-get install -y ffmpeg


## UTILITIES
RUN apt-get install -y vim
#RUN apt-get install -y wget


## APACHE2  basic installation
RUN apachectl -M
RUN a2enmod rewrite
RUN a2enmod expires
RUN service apache2 restart
RUN apachectl -M


################################################
## PHP modules
## Note: when installing from php5 for some modules we need to copy from php5/mods-available to local/etc/php/conf.d and create a simbolic link

RUN php -m

RUN apt-get install -y php5-common

RUN apt-get install -y php-calendar
#RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/calendar.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d && ln -s /usr/lib/php5/20131226/calendar.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/calendar.so

#RUN docker-php-ext-install calendar 

RUN docker-php-ext-install bcmath

RUN apt-get install -y php5-mhash
#RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/mhash.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d && ln -s /usr/lib/php5/20131226/mhash.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/mhash.so

RUN apt-get install -y php5-intl
RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/intl.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d && ln -s /usr/lib/php5/20131226/intl.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/intl.so

RUN apt-get install -y php5-mcrypt
RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/mcrypt.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d && ln -s /usr/lib/php5/20131226/mcrypt.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/mcrypt.so

RUN apt-get install -y php5-redis
RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/redis.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d && ln -s /usr/lib/php5/20131226/redis.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/redis.so

RUN apt-get install -y php5-mysql
RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/mysql.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d && ln -s /usr/lib/php5/20131226/mysql.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/mysql.so

RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/opcache.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d

RUN apt-get install -y php5-gd
RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/gd.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d && ln -s /usr/lib/php5/20131226/gd.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/gd.so

RUN apt-get install -y php5-gdcm
RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/gdcm.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d && ln -s /usr/lib/php5/20131226/gdcm.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/gdcm.so

RUN apt-get install -y php5-vtkgdcm
RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/vtkgdcm.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d && ln -s /usr/lib/php5/20131226/vtkgdcm.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/vtkgdcm.so

RUN apt-get install -y php5-ldap
RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/ldap.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d && ln -s /usr/lib/php5/20131226/ldap.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/ldap.so

RUN apt-get install -y php5-xsl
RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/xsl.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d && ln -s /usr/lib/php5/20131226/xsl.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/xsl.so

RUN apt-get install -y php5-tidy
RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/tidy.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d && ln -s /usr/lib/php5/20131226/tidy.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/tidy.so

RUN apt-get install -y php5-xmlrpc
RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/xmlrpc.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d && ln -s /usr/lib/php5/20131226/xmlrpc.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/xmlrpc.so

RUN apt-get install -y php5-pgsql
RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/pgsql.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d && ln -s /usr/lib/php5/20131226/pgsql.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/pgsql.so


RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/mysqli.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d && ln -s /usr/lib/php5/20131226/mysqli.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/mysqli.so
RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/pdo.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d && ln -s /usr/lib/php5/20131226/pdo.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/pdo.so
RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/pdo_mysql.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d && ln -s /usr/lib/php5/20131226/pdo_mysql.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/pdo_mysql.so
RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/pdo_pgsql.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d && ln -s /usr/lib/php5/20131226/pdo_pgsql.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/pdo_pgsql.so
RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/readline.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d && ln -s /usr/lib/php5/20131226/readline.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/readline.so

#RUN apt-get install -y php5-snmp
#RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/snmp.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d && ln -s /usr/lib/php5/20131226/snmp.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/snmp.so


RUN php -m


## REDIS
RUN apt-get install -y telnet redis-server
RUN apt-get install -y redis-server
RUN apt-get install -y npm

#RUN mkdir /composer-setup && mkdir /usr/local/bin/composer && wget https://getcomposer.org/installer -P /composer-setup && php /composer-setup/installer --install-dir=/usr/local/bin/composer && rm -Rf /composer-setup




################################################
## PHP extra modules
#RUN apt-get install -y php-horde-date-parser  ##The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get install -y php-horde-date-parser' returned a non-zero code: 100
#RUN apt-get install -y php-horde-date
#RUN apt-get install -y php-horde-timezone
#RUN apt-get install -y php-horde-timeobjects
#RUN apt-get install -y php-timer



#RUN apt-get install -y php-horde-icalendar
#RUN apt-get install -y php-horde-kronolith
#RUN apt-get install -y php-doctrine-dbal
#RUN apt-get install -y phpldapadmin
#RUN apt-get install -y php-horde-ldap
#RUN apt-get install -y php-net-ldap
#RUN apt-get install -y php-net-ldap2
#RUN apt-get install -y php-mdb2-driver-pgsql
#RUN apt-get install -y libnusoap-php
#RUN apt-get install -y php-soap
#RUN apt-get install -y php-fxsl
#RUN apt-get install -y php-horde-text-filter-csstidy
#RUN apt-get install -y php-pclzip
#RUN apt-get install -y libphp-pclzip

#RUN apt-get update

#RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/json.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d && ln -s /usr/lib/php5/20131226/json.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/json.so


#Manage PHP ini options from command line on Debian => https://howto.biapy.com/en/debian-gnu-linux/servers/php/manage-php-ini-options-from-command-line-on-debian
#RUN apt-get install -y php5-cli


### Note: Compare content

#PHP5
#cd /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d
#cd /etc/php5/mods-available/


#PHP 
#cd /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226
#cd /usr/lib/php5/20131226/



## Note: when module is php5 need to make it available inside php/extensions (create a simbolic link)
#RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/MODULE.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d && ln -s /usr/lib/php5/20131226/MODULE.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/MODULE.so

################################################






## WORK DIR
#COPY manyvids/ /var/www/html
#COPY src/ /var/www/html

# CONNECTIONS - PORTS
#EXPOSE 80

#########################################. Extra notes
#CMD ["redis-server"]

## Clean up Docker
#docker rm $(docker ps -a)
#docker rmi $(docker images)
#docker build -t mv1_img . 

## RUN REDIS 
#Open up another terminal
#docker  exec -it  xxxxxCOntainerId bash 
#root@bxxxxxCOntainerId:/var/www/html# redis-server

#If another terminal is needed to get acces to the container:
#Open up another terminal
#docker  exec -it  xxxxxCOntainerId bash 


## Not found modules. We have it in MAMP instance, not in DOCKER apt php list and not in php -m
#mysqli
#pdo_mysql
#pdo_pgsql
#shmop
#sockets
#sysvmsg
#sysvsem
#sysvshm
#wddx
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Veja o exemplo de como deve ser carregado o PHP.ini na própria documentação da biblioteca no PHP no Docker:

```
FROM php:7.2-fpm-alpine

# Use the default production configuration
RUN mv $PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini-production $PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini

# Override with custom opcache settings
COPY config/opcache.ini $PHP_INI_DIR/conf.d/
```

Nesse exemplo o autor escolheu utilizar a configuração de produção, por isso renomeou o arquivo php.ini-production para php.ini. Portanto no seu caso a se existir o arquivo /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini esse será de onde o PHP vai pegar a configuração.
E a pasta /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/ fica para as configurações das extensões, como no exemplo acima está sendo utilizada uma configuração propria do opcache.

Se você quiser utilizar uma configuração própria, basta copia-la do seu diretório para a pasta de configuração do PHP. Exemplo:

```
COPY config/php.ini $PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini
```

Segue o link da documentação: [doc](https://docs.docker.com/samples/library/php/#configuration)

Answer (score 0):

Voce pode validar o get do php com o ciclo de instalacao da linha 108 à 151 do dockerfile.

Tenta buscar os .ini em /etc/php/5.6/.... deve estar ai, mas dentro do box q vc criou, então faça o attach ID_docker_file p acessar.

Tem q verificar se o sapi foi instalado, talvez falte pq não vi no file o wget ou apt-get dele, onde vc poderia utilizar o fpm.

Se tiver algum problema p subir app vai mandando nos coments.

Comment: Oi Luiz, depois da sua idéia fiz uma busca e achei o php.ini dentro do arquivo mencionado. Mas não estou entendendo como esse arquivo não está sendo considerado quando fazemos o display das configurações do php.ini no browser.  eu vou postar o meu Dockfile completo.

Comment: Acho que eu entendi parte do problema.  Parece que o Dockerfile oficial, está instalando o php5.6 dentro de `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` e depois, na linha 31 ele aponta `ENV PHP_INI_DIR /usr/local/etc/php`. Ele espera que nesse diretório tenha um arquivo php.ini. Acho que eu devo então criar um link simbólico em  `/usr/local/etc/php` apontando para `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` Mas continuo sem entender de onde está sendo carregado esse php.ini.

Answer (score 0):

Uma forma muito fácil de saber qual dos php.ini que existem no servidor, o que realmente está sendo usado, é utilizar o comando abaixo:

```
php -i | grep php.ini
```

Pois as vezes se tem vários php.ini no servidor.

Comment: não sei porque negativaram, a resposta atende exatamente ao pedido da pergunta, de maneira bem direta, mas atende.

Answer (score -3):

Os arquivos de configuração do php.ini, quando utilizados pelo docker, encontram-se no /opt/docker/etc/php. Tive esse mesmo problema e passei dias pesquisando. O caminho (/etc/php7/php.ini) não sobrescreve as alterações efetuadas no mapeamento do volume.

Altere para o /opt/docker/etc/php/php.ini. Acredito que isso lhe ajudará.